# How to add touch and scroll event on a button on a top of scroll view Corona?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm creating level selection scene in corona. To accomplish this I have used `scrollview` and I have added a group of buttons to this `scrollview`.

But my problem is that I can scroll when I touch the background of the `scrollview` but I when I touch any of this button the scroll view didn't scroll.

What I need is to handle to events `onpress` on the button and scroll for the scroll view
so any ideas to how I can scroll the scroll view if I touch and hold on the button then I scrolled my finger?

Comment: Sounds like you aren't using `if event.phase == "ended" then`... Which causes the button to register immediately upon touch.

Comment: yes i have used this for click event and then take me to another seen 
so should i use event.phase == "began" to scroll the view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem using `takefocus` method inside the button listener with this code

```
if ( phase == "moved" ) then
    local dy = math.abs( ( event.y - event.yStart ) )
    -- If the touch on the button has moved more than 10 pixels,
    -- pass focus back to the scroll view so it can continue scrolling
    if ( dy > 10 ) then
        scrollView:takeFocus( event )
    end
end
```